# visual studioのビルド時のdllのパスについて

Tags: visual-studio

visual studioでビルド実行時、

1>〇〇.vcxproj -> C:\trunk...(略)...\GUM.\Debug\〇〇.dll
1>指定されたパスが見つかりません。
1>プロジェクト "〇〇.vcxproj" のビルドが終了しました。
========== すべてリビルド: 1 正常終了、0 失敗、0 スキップ ==========

と結果が出力されたのですが、
dllのフォルダパスで、GUMとDebugの間の「.」は何ですか？
このドットがなければフォルダパスは問題ないのですが、このドットがあることでパスが見つからないといわれているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studioのプロジェクトファイルは、実は[MSBuild](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2017)というビルドツールのプロジェクトファイルであり、Visual StudioはMSBuildを呼び出しているに過ぎません。Visual Studio上の設定がそのままMSBuildの変数となります。

> GUMとDebugの間の「.」は何ですか？

Visual Studio上の設定のどこかで「.」のような値を設定してしまった結果です。MSBuildは変数で指定された値を展開したに過ぎません。どこでそのような設定を行ったのかはプロジェクトファイルを確認するほかありません。

[MSBuild プロジェクト ビルドの出力の詳細](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-dialog-box-projects-and-solutions-build-and-run?view=vs-2017)の設定でログレベルを上げ詳細な情報を得ることはできますが、MSBuildの仕組みに精通している必要があります。